# How to deploy the Web service in to tomcat 7 from out side of eclipse juno?

Tags: web-services, tomcat

i am very new to web services and i have one problem please suggest me .. i.e i have a WSDL(SOAP) file and with that i created the Web Service-server and web service-Client using Top-Down approach with JAX-WS in eclipse Juno Java EE. i integrated the Tomcat 7 with that Eclipse and from eclipse its working fine.

But my problem is i need to run the Tomcat from out side of the eclipse and i need to deploy the web service in to the tomcat. i don't want to run the Tomcat using eclipse? i just need to run the client from eclipse but i dont want to run the tomcat from eclipse. Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

File -> Export -> Web -> War (configure where to create it)

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a tomcat application consist of building a war file then deploying it. We call this servlet.

### Building the WAR

As you already have your server code, you should now complet the WEB-INF/web.xml file. This file describe the path of your servlet(your server code), on the tomcat server. Depending of your framework you can have some configuration to add in your META-INF/context.xml file.

In an eclipse project, thoses file are generaly under a directory name 'webapp' in your project. (src/main/webapp  for a maven project).

First you must use the javaee & javaweb tools of eclipse to build a war file that contains all yours libs, files, class and web.xml
Alternativly you can use a maven build process to get a war, if you use maven.

### Deploying the war

After installing tomcat, the deployement is as simple as drop the .war file is deploy directory of the home-directory of tomcat. Then your application is usable on default port 8080.

If you have install also the manager webapp of tomcat, you can see all yours currently deployed application in the manager `http://myurl:8080/manager/html`.

When you install tomcat, let be sure that your eclipse pseudo server is shutdown, or your tomcat server will have problem to get it's port and startup.